# cufflinks: scatter plot with heatmap

Tags: plotly

I have a pandas dataframe:

```
A B C
1 1 0.1
2 3 -0.2
1 2 2
```

I want to plot (scatter) with `x=A` and `y=B` and the color as the value of `C`.

So I tried

```
import cufflinks
df.iplot(kind='heatmap', mode='markers', 
    y='B', x = 'A', 
    z = 'C',
    filename='cufflinks/simple-heatmap')
```

and I have an error:

```
944                                 colorscale=[[float(_)/(len(scale)-1),scale[_]] for _ in range(len(scale))]
    945                                 center_scale = kwargs.get('center_scale',None)
--> 946                                 zmin=z.min()
    947                                 zmax=z.max()
    948                                 if center_scale is not None:

AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'min'
```

Answer (score 0):

From your question I understand you want a `heatmap` and a `scatter` plot on the same graph, so below is a working example. Please provide more details since your question seems ambiguous.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objs as go
from plotly.offline import download_plotlyjs,init_notebook_mode,plot,iplot
import cufflinks as cf
cf.go_offline()
init_notebook_mode(connected=True)

test = df.iplot(kind='heatmap', mode='markers', 
    y='B', x = 'A', 
    z = 'C',
    filename='cufflinks/simple-heatmap', asFigure=True)
test2 = df.iplot(kind='scatter', y='B', x = 'A', colors=["red", "green", "yellow"], mode="markers+lines", asFigure=True)
test['data'].append(test2['data'][0])
iplot(test)
```

Comment: So the idea is we need 2 graphs and then merge them?

Comment: @TiếuThủy From my understanding you need two graphs (heatmap+scatter) in the  same plot like how it is in my example. Is what I have made relevant? if not what is it lacking?